# Faster Duration between two db's/tables

Tags: mysql

The duration to the following query is around 8 mins. I am looking for the average business days between two dates and am using two db's and tables with one being a calendar table. Is there a more efficient way of making the duration for the following query faster?

```
select avg(datediff(e.column1, e.column2)) as 'diff' 
from DB1 e
inner join db2.table1 pd on e.column3 = pd.column1
where pd.calendar_day_in_week not in (1,7)
```

Comment: Have you indexed `calendar_day_in_week`?

Answer (score 0):

Is e.column3 and pd.column1 indexed? I think is the join that makes query go slow. Try this

```
select avg(datediff(e.column1, e.column2)) as 'diff' 
from DB1 e
inner join (SELECT column1 FROM db2.table1 WHERE calendar_day_in_week not in (1,7)) AS pd on e.column3 = pd.column1
```

Do the where on the table1 first, so you get smaller chunk table for the join.

Comment: it's unlikely that would make it faster, although it's tough to say without a explain plan. That said `inner join db2.table1 pd on e.column3 = pd.column1 AND pd.calendar_day_in_week not in (1,7)` would likely have the same effect while keeping any indexes on `pd.column1` usable

Comment: Yeah, I think it depends on how big is the table size and pd.column1 and e.column3, whether they are indexed. Cause it works for me when I have 100,000 records for each table which only 1,000 after the Where condition and result only less than 100.  But never know unless you try.

Comment: calendar_day_in_week was not indexed and when that was done it worked! thanks for all your help!